# When is the configuration initialized for a Laravel application? or when DB::connection is set?

Tags: php, laravel, configuration

I have a Middleware that changes a database config dynamically like this:

```php
config(['database.connections.mysql.database'=> 'newDatabaseName']);
```

And in each model, I have `$connection = 'mysql'` explicitly set.

Inside of my model constructor:

```php
logger()->info(get_class($this). ' database: ' . config('database.connections.mysql.database'));
logger()->info(get_class($this). ' database: ' . DB::connection($this->connection)->getDatabaseName());
```

The output is:

```
newDatabaseName
oldDatabaseName
```

where `newDatabaseName` is the database I set in the middleware and `oldDatabasename` is the .env database name.

So basically I successfully set the database name in the configuration, but the model is still using the .env database name for some reason.

Any ideas why this happens?

I have other middlewares applied to these routes:

```php
SubstituteBindings::class,
ChangeLocale::class,
HandleCors::class,
```

I thought it was because of the "SubstituteBinding" middleware, but I have tried to put my middleware before and after it, it doesn't make a difference.

I'm using laravel 5.6

Comment: In Laravel Application always configuration in "bootstrap/app.php"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found what's going on. 
DatabaseManager caches all the connections for the first time, this will fix it:

```php
config(['database.connections.mysql.database' => 'newDatabaseName']);

DB::purge('mysql');

DB::reconnect('mysql');
```

Here is the post I found that talks about the exact problem: 
https://divinglaravel.com/understanding-how-laravel-configures-database-connections

Comment: During the process, I found that model observer registering in AppServicePrivoder's boot method runs before middlewares so moving  the registration to each Model would reduce some noises.

Answer (score 0):

You can dynamically set databases. This is going to override `.evn` and `config/database.php` file.

```php
class MyMiddleware
{
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        Config::set('database.connections.mysql.database', $request->path());

        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

Kernel

```php
class Kernel extends HttpKernel
{
    /**
     * The application's global HTTP middleware stack.
     *
     * These middleware are run during every request to your application.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $middleware = [
        MyMiddleware::class,
        \App\Http\Middleware\TrustProxies::class,
        \Fruitcake\Cors\HandleCors::class,
        \App\Http\Middleware\CheckForMaintenanceMode::class,
        \Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\ValidatePostSize::class,
        \App\Http\Middleware\TrimStrings::class,
        \Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\ConvertEmptyStringsToNull::class,
    ];
```

Now test it! If you have two databases `laravel` and `stTest`. And the name field in user table is `stTest` and `laravel` as well.

```php
Route::get('/stTest', function () {
    return User::first()->name; //stTest
});

Route::get('/laravel', function () {
    return User::first()->name; //laravel
});
```

Comment: it makes sense but still doesn't solve my problem. My problem is that it's being overridden after it's set, not when how it's set.

Comment: @DeyiKong, no, it's not. in your routes, the middleware takes precedence over `.env`. Where and when you want to use it?

Comment: @DeyiKong or did I misunderstood your question?

Comment: probably you misunderstood my question. My question is not how to set up a middleware to change the database, it's when my config is overridden when a model is fetched. Thanks anyway tho.

Comment: @DeyiKong , ok, so I still do not understand why `when` is important for you, the end result is your middleware takes precedence. what feature do you want to achieve?

Comment: In my case, config is set successfully by the middleware, even in each model's constructor, config still has the db name I set in the middleware, but the connection the model uses is the .env database name. so the problem is not that the config is not set successfully, it is that `when` the model is fetched, the connection is using the .env database name.

Answer (score 0):

Laravel fetches and stores configs in an array when bootstraps the application.

When the app comes up it reads the database configs and initiates the database connection based on the configurations that you will override in middleware. So, updating the database connection configs won't affect the connection itself.

**Solution:**

Define multiple connections in `config/database.php` then set the default connection name in your middleware instead of setting the database name.

`config(['database.default' => $connectionName]);`

And of course, don't set the connection name in models explicitly.

Comment: Same issue. Overridden still happens no matter which config I set in the middleware.

Comment: Please move the `SubstituteBindings` middleware after this middleware and test  it again

Comment: I've tried putting it before or after it. it doesn't work.